# NodeJS: Download File and convert to binary string

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary, fs

I am pretty new to Node.js and struggle with current topic:

I am calling an API which returns me a file (audio.amr). I now need to convert this file during runtime, without saving it, to a binary string in order to pass it further.

I tried passing the received object to the "fs" module, but without any luck.

```
requestify.request('https://some-url.com', {
                method: 'GET'
            }).then(function (response) { var obj = response.getBody() }
```

In "obj" is now a file returned that I need to convert to a binary string.

Comment: Can you post your code maybe so we can try to see what's happening out there?

Comment: May be this will help you http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-19-nodejs-writable-streams.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) to hold binary data, then convert the ArrayBuffer to a Hex string. To get the raw body from requestify, you'll have to use the `.body` property instead of the `getBody()` function, according to [their documentation](https://github.com/ranm8/requestify).

You'll have to check what the raw body's type is and convert it to an ArrayBuffer if necessary.

```
// ...
var obj = response.body; // Get the raw body
var arrayBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode (obj); // Convert String data to ArrayBuffer (might need to be changed)
var hexString = bufferToHex (arrayBuffer);
// ...

function bufferToHex (buffer) {
    return Array
        .from (new Uint8Array (buffer))
        .map (b => b.toString (16).padStart (2, "0"))
        .join ("");
}
```

**Update:**

Since apparently `requestify` has no way to handle raw body data, I suggest you use `node-fetch`, a `window.fetch` polyfill for nodeJS.

Your code with it would look as follows:

```
const fetch = require ("node-fetch");

fetch(yourUrl, {
    method: 'GET'
}).then(function (response) { 
    return response.arrayBuffer ();
}).then(function (arrayBuf) {
    const hexString = bufferToHex (arrayBuf);
    // Do whatever you want
});
```

Comment: Instead of using `new TextEncoder().encode (obj);` I used `Buffer.from(obj)` which is returning me something, but when I decode it to base64 for further analysis, the file seems to be corrupt. You stated that I should check what the raw body type is...it is a sound AMR file, is there a difference which type of buffer to use?

Comment: Apparently, `requestify` cannot handle raw body data. I'd suggest you use `node-fetch`, which is a `window.fetch` polyfill for NodeJS. I've updated my post.

Comment: Thank you so much! This finally did it!